# Converting VB code snippet to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have to convert following Visual Basic code snippet to C#.
I used Telerik Converter.
But C# compiler shows error (type compatibility).
What will be the exact syntax for following code in C#?

`TotalMessages` is of type `int`.

```
Select Case TP_DCS
   Case ENUM_TP_DCS.UCS2
      TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length / 4) \ 66 + ((TP_UD.Length / 4 Mod 66) = 0)
   Case ENUM_TP_DCS.DefaultAlphabet
     TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length \ 266) - ((TP_UD.Length Mod 266) = 0)
End Select
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh..i want this code in C#

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: try here: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @Robert i used telerik online converter but, totalmessages is of type, the expression is not evaluated and not assignable to totalmessages, followint is the error i get "cannot apply operator - to operands of type int and bool"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  **Developer fusion** to convert your VB code to C#. Click [Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to go to the conversion page.

Your C# code would be as mentioned below :

```
switch (TP_DCS) 
{
    case ENUM_TP_DCS.UCS2:
        TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length / 4) / 66 + ((TP_UD.Length / 4 % 66) == 0);
        break;
    case ENUM_TP_DCS.DefaultAlphabet:
        TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length / 266) - ((TP_UD.Length % 266) == 0);
        break;
}
```

**Update :**

```
switch (TP_DCS)
{
    case ENUM_TP_DCS.UCS2:
        TotalMessages = ((TP_UD.Length / 4) / 66) + ((TP_UD.Length / 4 % 66) == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        break;
    case ENUM_TP_DCS.DefaultAlphabet:
        TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length / 266) - ((TP_UD.Length % 266) == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is NOT the same as the code posted above. You have not differentiated by the \ and / operators.

Comment: @SpiderCode but how can i perform + or - operation between 'int' and 'bool'

Comment: what about **(TP_UD.Length / 4 % 66) == 0** condition ? if it is true then 1 else 0 ?

Comment: see updated answer. Here I have put that "if condition becomes true then 1 else 0". you can change it.

Comment: This answer is still not correct. You have ignored the fact that the original code makes use of the / operator to return an int instead of a double.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first line giving you the trouble

try changing  `TotalMessages is of type int` to `Dim TotalMessages As Integer`

Should be something like

```
int TotalMessages = 0;

switch (TP_DCS) {
    case ENUM_TP_DCS.UCS2:
        TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length / 4) / 66 + ((TP_UD.Length / 4 % 66) == 0);
        break;
    case ENUM_TP_DCS.DefaultAlphabet:
        TotalMessages = (TP_UD.Length / 266) - ((TP_UD.Length % 266) == 0);
        break;
    default:
        TotalMessages =0;
}
```